# Check which one of two buttons has been pressed and pass a value to sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

I have an activity with two buttons. Both buttons bring you to the next activity and at the same time a value is being given to sharedpreferences. I want to access this value in my very last activity.

1. How do I check which of the two buttons has been pressed?
2. What is the problem in my code? I always get the same value in the end. So it seems like I always press the same button, which I don't.

Here the first activity where the two buttons are in:

```js
public void imagebutton (){
        
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Akt1.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("name2", "Geschlecht");

                editor.clear();
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(Akt1.this, Akt2.class));
            }
        });
    }

               //buttonclick mit datapass gemixt

    private void imagebutton1 () {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("name","Geschlecht");
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

And here the code from the last activity where I want to access the value that has been passed to sharedpreferences from the buttonclick:

```js
public class Akt6 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Hiermit Layout mit Activity verbinden
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akt6);



        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = preferences.getString("Name",null);
        name ="Männlich";

        SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name2 = preferences.getString("Name", "default");
        name2 ="Weiblich";
        //zeige Wert on screen

        TextView textView19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        textView19.setText(name);
```

Comment: Just so you know, Java and JavaScript are very different languages. I've updated your tags to use the correct language.

Comment: value will always be `name ="Männlich";` and `name` and `Name` is different

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same value because of this:

```
String name = preferences.getString("Name", null);
...
String name2 = preferences.getString("Name", "default");
```

You're using the same key "Name". You stored the values with the keys "name" and "name2".
So if you want to get those values you need to write something like this:

```
String name = preferences.getString("name", null);
...
String name2 = preferences.getString("name2", "default");
```

Also you are storing always the same value "Geschlecht":

```
editor.putString("name2", "Geschlecht");
editor.putString("name","Geschlecht");
```

Comment: okay i made your changes but in the last activity where i access the data, i still only get " Männlich" no matter what button i pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you doing on your activity, but if you need to know wich button has been pressed you can do the follow:

To your button listeners add this:

```
public void imagebutton (){

    ...
    editor.putString("name2", "Geschlecht");
    editor.putString("ButtonPressed","Button1"); // This is the new line
    ...
}

...

public void imagebutton1 (){

    ...
    editor.putString("name2", "Geschlecht");
    editor.putString("ButtonPressed","Button2"); // This is the new line
    ...
}
```

Then, to get the value of the button pressed in your activity do this:

```
...
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String button = preferences.getString("ButtonPressed","");
if(!button.isEmpty()){
    switch(button){
        case "Button":
            //You have pressed the first button
            break;
        case "Button2":
            //You have pressed the second button
            break;
    }
}
```

You should use constants for every String passed as sharedpref name and value to avoid human mistakes on your code.
Good luck!

Comment: sorry you didn´t understand my problem. I have two button: 1. Male and 2. Female. If for e.g. Male is pressed i want to show in the last activity of the app " Male".

Comment: Well, replace "Button" for "Male" and "Button2" for "Female" and you got it

Answer (score 0):

> What is the problem in my code? I always get the same value in the
>   end. So it seems like I always press the same button, which I don't.

**1.** In your method `imagebutton1()`, you are storing value for `name` into different sharedPreferences (`myprefs`):

```
// Akt1
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and trying to get value of `name` from `default` sharedPreferences:

```
// Akt6
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

**2.** You have used KEY `name` to store value:

```
 // Akt1
editor.putString("name","Geschlecht");
```

and getting value by using different KEY `Name` which is totally wrong.

```
// Akt6
String name = preferences.getString("Name", null);
```

> How do I check which of the two buttons has been pressed?

**SOLUTION:**

1. Use same `SharedPreferences` to store and retrieve value.
2. Use same KEY `"name"` to store and retrieve value for `name` from `SharedPreferences`

**Update your code as below:**

**`Akt1.java`**

```
public void imageButton (){

    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Akt1.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("name", "Male");
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(Akt1.this, Akt2.class));
        }
    });
}

private void imageButton1 () {
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Akt1.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("name", "Female");
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(Akt1.this, Akt2.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**`Akt6.java`**

```
public class Akt6 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akt6);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = preferences.getString("name", "default");

        TextView textView19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        textView19.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~